# Passing Variable to PHP from dynamic dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem passing a variable selected from a dynamic drop dropdown to a PHP file.  I want the PHP to select all rows in a db table that match the variable. Here's the code so far:

select.php

---

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#type").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        var cat = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        var type = $("select#type option:selected").attr('value');

        if(cat>0 && type>0)
        {
            var result = $("select#type option:selected").html();
            $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'display.php',
            data: {'result': myval},
            });



        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
    <form id="select_form">
        Choose a category:<br />
        <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    Choose a type:<br />
    <select id="type">
         <option value="0">choose...</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <?php include "display.php"; ?>

    <div id="result2"></div>         
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the display.php that I want the variable passed to.  This file will select the criteria from the db and then print the results in select.php.

```
<?php


class DisplayResults
{
protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DbConnect();
    }

    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function ShowResults()

    {

        $myval = $_POST['result'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM specialities WHERE 'myval'=sp_name";
        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
           echo "<table border='1'>";
           echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>Code</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['sp_name'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['sp_code'];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
            echo "</table>";
        //} 
        }
        return $category;
    }

}

$res = new DisplayResults();
?>
```

I'd really appreciate any help.  Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Link to db diagram:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeqVX.jpg

The first dropdown draws from the profession table, the second from the specialties table.  What I'd like to do is to display all of the rows in the jobs table that match the specialty selected in the dropdown box.  This will require the result from the variable (result) from the dropdown to be converted into the spec_code that is in the job table.  Not sure exactly how to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: $sql = `"SELECT * FROM specialities WHERE 'myval'=".$myval.""`;? Also don't forget to validate posted data.

Comment: Where r u calling ShowResults

Comment: It seems that ajax doesn't post any variables too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's impossible to answer your question correctly as we don't know whether it's the category or type field which is to be used in your SQL query.

Below is some concept code which should point you in the right direction.

### But first, a few comments..

**HTML/JS**

1. When you're checking that the `cat` and `type` variables are 'greater than 0' on submit you should parse the values to integers first as post values are sent as text by default.
2. Your `myval` value is impossible to decipher, please specify your intention.
3. For further reference your repeated jQuery queries like `$("select#type")` can be stored in a variable like `var $type = $("select#type")` and then be referenced like `$type.attr('disabled', 'disabled')`. I'm not 100% sure how jQuery caches the results but in theory it should require less processing from jQuery, also it's reduces [duplicated code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

**PHP**

1. Check that the supervariable indexes are set by using `isset()` or `!empty()` before using the values otherwise an warning (or notification, can't recall) will be shown. So instead of `$myvar = $_POST['myfield']` do `$myvar = isset( $_POST['myfield'] ) ? $_POST['myfield'] : "";`
2. **Make sure that you escape or cast/sanitize values before they're using a SQL query.** For the MySQL library you'd use the [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.
3. The **mysql** library is deprecated and prone to hacks. Usage of the newer **mysqli** library is highly recommended.
4. Again, no idea if the `sp_name` column is for the category or type field. I've included both.
5. All though it weirdly works to put the value first in your where expression (before the colum name) it's against normal practice and not recommended. Instead of `'myval'=sp_name` do `sp_name='myval'`.
6. Fixed your loop `showResults()`.
7. You never called the method `showResults()` in *display.php*. Also note that it returns a value so we must also print it to screen.

### HTML/JS

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#category").change(function(){
        $("select#type").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("select#type").html("<option>wait...</option>");            var id = $("select#category option:selected").attr('value');
        $.post("select_type.php", {id:id}, function(data){
            $("select#type").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#type").html(data);
        });
    });
    $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
        // Fetch values and parse them to integers
        var cat = parseInt( $("#category").val(), 10 );
        var type = parseInt( $("#type").val(), 10 );

        if(cat>0 && type>0)
        {
            $("#result").html('your choice: '+type);

                        // Prepare data
                        var data = {
                            category: cat,
                            type: type
                        }

            $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'display.php',
                            data: data
            });

        }
        else
        {
            $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
    <form id="select_form" action="">
        Choose a category:<br />
        <select id="category">
            <?php echo $opt->ShowCategory(); ?>
        </select>
    <br /><br />
    Choose a type:<br />
    <select id="type">
         <option value="0">choose...</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <?php include "display.php"; ?>

    <div id="result2"></div>         
</body>
</html>
```

### display.php

```
<?php


class DisplayResults
{
protected $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->DbConnect();
    }

    protected function DbConnect()
    {
        include "db_config.php";
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
        mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
        return TRUE;
    }

    public function ShowResults()

    {   
        // Fetch values from POST and escape/cast the values to prevent SQL injection
        $category = (int) ( isset( $_POST['category'] ) ? $_POST['category'] : 0 );
        $type = (int) ( isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? $_POST['type'] : 0 );

        // Use the values in your SQL query 
        // 
        // PLEASE CHANGE THE COLUMN NAMES TO MATCH YOUR SOLUTION
        //==================
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM specialities WHERE category='". $category ."' and type='". $type ."' ";


        $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
           echo "<table border='1'>";
           echo "<tr><th>id</th><th>Code</th></tr>";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['sp_name'];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row['sp_code'];
            echo "</td></tr>";
        //} 
        }
                echo "</table>";
        return $category;
    }

}

$res = new DisplayResults();

// Get and print results
echo $res->showResults();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've added a link to the db diagram, hope things help to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @jsizemore5665 I see, thanks for supplying the information. Do you need me to update my code or are you able to adjust your code accordingly? Immediately I can see the column name you want to use is `id_type` instead of `sp_name`.